# Best way to offer a large amount of selectable options (without using Javascript)?

Tags: input, html, data, selection

I come from stackoverflow and have no answers for this one, so I turn to the UI guys for assistance.

Let's say I have a library application that allows a user (librarian) to add a book to the database. One of the features is tagging an author to a certain book. A book can have more than one author, so a UI that allows multiple tags is required. I really want it to follow the *progressive enhancement* approach, from a basic functional site to a JS/CSS enhanced version.

I already have a database of at least 450 authors. For the enhanced version an auto-complete and editable select is in my arsenal and has proven effective. The problem is with the basic version, especially for mobile devices and incapable browsers (like opera mini perhaps?).

From a programmer's view, a multiple-select `<select>` box should do. But by reading at least 3 UX books, a multiple-select `<select>` is a "no go" since there is no indication (unless explicitly mentioned) that a select is multiple-enabled. Also not good for the physically-challenged people since you have to hold down <kbd>Command</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (PC) to multiple select. Mobile browsers have none of those keys also! To add to that, 450+ selections in one box?

In summary:

- 450+ items to choose from
- selecting multiple items
- progressive enhancement approach
- this is for the basic view (No Javascript, limited CSS)
- mainly targeted to non-modern and limited feature browsing devices (like opera mini and mobile browsers that have no JavaScript capability)

What's the best way to tackle this situation? How did they even do this prior to web 2.0?

Comment: The "No JS" requirement limits your options for making things usable/responsive in a web app severely, can you elaborate on that pre-req?

Comment: I wouldn't assume mobile browsers can't do javascript or CSS. Opera Mini butchers Javascript but Safari, Android's browser, Firefox mobile and Dolphin all run JS pretty well best I can tell. Don't limit those users because someone might be browsing on his 5 year old palm pilot.

Comment: Progressive enhancement means that people who aren't using good tools don't get the best service. It's their own fault. Give them something that works, be it a `<select>` box or empty `<input>` field, and move on. You're probably considering less than 1% of your users. Do some demographics testing to find out how many poor souls you actually need to help.

Comment: @zzzzBov that would be the "*graceful degradation*" approach - which, as the book "*designing with progressive enhancement*" states is like saying to the user "just upgrade". but what if they can't? what if they prefer old hardware/software coz they can't afford to buy new tech? what if i also wanted a "mobile-enabled administration from anywhere" some time in the future? that's why i turned to the web as my platform (and left Java and Flash+AIR) where it's decentralized, where all control and adaptivity is passed on the developer and the service provider.

Comment: @fskreuz: Your customers are libraries. Their only constraint on upgrades is budget, not preference for old hardware.

Comment: the only difference between "graceful degradation" and "progressive enhancement" is the order in which you create features. If you start with your low-level users, then it's p-e, if you start with your high-level users, then it's g-d. Either way, your low level users don't get the full experience, and typically make up a small minority of a user base. That's why i recommended demographics testing.

Comment: from the same book i read, they are different also. *progressive enhancement* builds a *functional* foundation and enhances it while having that functional fall-back in case things won't work. *graceful degradation* on the other hand is creating a modern functionality and adapts it backwards with a possibility that *they won't work on all devices in that direction*. and like i said "***Let's say*** *I have a library application that allows a user (librarian) to add a book to the database*" - the library is just an example of the type of field where i will hopefully deploy. but i get your point

Comment: @fskreuz: You're right that progressive enhancement builds a foundation and improves the visuals. However, there are some interactions that cannot be simplified below a certain point to remain comfortably usable. Selecting from a 450+ item list is one of those interactions.

Comment: @fskreuz: If we've answered your question, you can select the best solution so that if anyone comes across the same problem in the future, they know the course of action.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A dropdown with 450+ values is extremely unusable on any device, including desktop. But you say that you're only looking for a solution for the basic mobile version, so let's stick to that.

Probably the best way to simplify this for the mobile is to have a first screen/popup display the alphabet, then as you tap a letter you drill down to the list of authors beginning with that letter. Your largest list per letter, even for the most common letters, should be at about 30-40 values, which can be scrolled easily. Then you tap a name to select it, press Back to return to the alphabet and proceed to select additional authors until you press Done. That's the most standard approach for mobile, based on simple linear navigation.

A better way would be to develop something resembling a phone book app, but I guess you can't do that on a web app without JS.

Comment: This works only if they build a separate version of the app for both low-end mobiles & desktops. The changes in the navigation structure are too drastic.

Comment: This is only for mobiles, and that's the solution that can work without JS, as requested by the OP.

Comment: this one i see in mobile web email and mobile facebook.

Answer (score 12):

Unless you have auto complete, a list with 450+ options is never very user friendly, and always hard to use, especially when you even allow multiple selections.

Given that the task to add books to the library is a very common one, that should be done fast, I would propose a more simpler backend-powered solution using two simple steps:

1. First the user is presented with a simple input field where he simply enters author names. For multiple authors they are simply comma-separated.
2. On submit, the backend splits those entries and tries to find existing database entries for them. If you find a unique match, choose that author. If you find multiple possibilities, retain them all.
3. Present the user your results for him to check. In case of multiple possibilites, make him choose the correct match using a simple select box. When no match was found, allow him to create the author in that step (and maybe ask for more detailed information as well). Do that for each comma-separated value you have found.
4. On the final submit, you should have all your information.

Comment: i'm actually doing this for the mean time. but i have never thought of steps 3 and 4.

Answer (score 10):

Why not try something like what you get in the iOS Mail app.

[image]

1. A simple text input field
2. Drop down auto suggest (just like in Google Search)
3. When you have added a single item (like *author* in your case), you can type another one, by pushing the <kbd>+</kbd> button at the end of the input field (and previously entered items can be deleted ony by one.)

This solution could easily be used on a smart phone and desktop as well. I think that for 100+ elements some kind of "search" solution has to be used.

Comment: This is exactly what the OP is doing on high-end devices. However, he is asking for a low-end solution.

Comment: i know that some devices have a mandatory "auto-complete" feature because they can do it. but don't take back the answer. it might be useful soon.

Answer (score 5):

It's great that you're doing progressive enhancement! However, you're creating a creating a problem for yourself where there's none.

The UX approach is to think about the user and the environment where the product is being used. So let's look at your concerns:

- List box requires to hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd> to select multiple items, which isn't too accessible for disabled users.

  1. How many of your users (librarians) have severe motor disability that prevents them from holding down the required keys with one hand and moving the mouse with the other hand? - Not that many.
  2. Is there any assistive technology that allows people with motor disabilities use keyboards efficiently? - Yes (on-screen keyboards & special physical keyboards).
- Multiple selection in list box has low affordance because users don't know about holding down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>.

  1. Can you improve the affordance of multiple selection? - Yes, you can include explicit instructions about it.
- Mobile devices don't have <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd> keys or may have JavaScript-unfriendly browsers.

  1. How often will the system be used from a mobile device? - Maybe occasionally.
  2. What devices don't have <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd> keys? - Nearly all of them.
  3. What devices use primarily Opera Mini and other JavaScript-unfriendly browsers? - Older devices.
  4. What other characteristics do those older devices have? - They have less powerful CPUs, smaller screens, and slower Internet connections.
  5. How usable will a 450+ item list be on such devices? - Highly unusable because it would render & scroll slowly.
  6. What kind of device is likely to be used to enter book information away from the desk? - A tablet or similar because of the amount of text entry necessary.
  7. Do those devices support modern JavaScript? - Absolutely.

Consolidating all of the above, you shouldn't worry about list boxes for mobile devices or disabled users. In fact, you should make the simplest mobile version read-only and remove editing & creation capabilities from it so that users don't even try it. At the same time, a list box will be completely usable to anyone in the simplest version for desktop browsers as long as you instruct users on how to select multiple items.

Comment: +1 for make it read only and creating a problem where there isn't one.

Comment: Really thorough analysis. Great answer. If you could make the degraded experience great without JavaScript, why build the enhanced version?

Comment: @ChristopherJamesCalo: Thanks. The thing with progressive enhancement is that some interactions can't go below a certain level. It's impossible to make large lists of data usable without JS and CSS tricks, so when those aren't available the feature has to be dropped.

Comment: Agreed, @dnbrv. Sorry if it sounded like I was asking you a clarifying question. My question was rhetorical and meant to support your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would start the web page wih a single drop down box which would include all authors. Then, under that, have a check box that says 'add another author'. This would do what is expected, probably through javascript, and the user would be able to continue adding authors.

Comment: Hi austen, welcome to UX! Could you explain how you arrived at this conclusion? Perhaps by referencing a project you did, or a book you read? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to do multiple selection and a multi select box didn't allow for columns to display more data and the users do not know how to use a mulit select box in any case.

So I created a div with scroll bars, and in your case you could create multiple divs to suit your style (e.g. a div per letter of alphabet for authors).

Here is how mine came out to give you an idea:

[image]

Obviously you will have to play with the spacing and size to match your preferred device.

Please note that this is only a suggestion.

Comment: Can't stand scrollbars in webpages... usually ends up feeling like I have to browse a webpage through a key-hole. I'd say, either just show the whole thing, or do it in a separate step.

Comment: And most of the time they don’t work on touch devices…

Comment: Svish: I haven't worked with a touch device before, but I can see where you are coming from.
poke: How can a web compliant device not handle standard/basic html and css2? IE7 handles it (can't test on lower settings)

Comment: interesting approach compared to the "sea of checkboxes" answer. as far as i know, this won't be that "nice" on small screen devices. quite bulky. but it work work well on a PC. i'll take note of this.

Answer (score 1):

Even without the use of javascript you could try using some kind of autocomplete on the server side.

The user inputs the `name` (or part of it) manually and hits `search`.
That information is processed by the server and gives back a simple html list (with checkboxes) of possible answers.

On the bottom there would be 2 buttons: `add` and `add & complete`

This allows the user to add the name(s) from the current list and then go back to add more, or add the name(s) from this list and complete adding authors.

I'm not a UI expert so I don't know how intuitive it would be to use, but the technical side of it should be fine!